# Very Difficult SQL query into one (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm stacked with this query. I need to search for a word into different tables with different 
structures. I have only one search box and i'm making this three querys to find results in different places. How can I make all this in only one query to filter all together????

1) IN THIS QUERY (FROM PHP) I SEARCH A WORD "$palabra_buscar" INTO THE DESCRIPTION OF TABLE "VIDEOS", THE NAME, AND DESCRIPTION FROM TABLE "PROGRAMAS" USING AN INNER JOIN OF THE TABLE "programas_videos"

```
SELECT * FROM videos 
                 INNER JOIN programas_videos ON videos.id_video = programas_videos.id_video 
                 INNER JOIN programas ON programas_videos.id_prog = programas.id_prog 
                 WHERE programas.nombre_prog LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
                 OR programas.descrip_larga LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
                 OR videos.descrip_larga LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
                 GROUP BY videos.id_video DESC LIMIT 10
```

2) I HAVE THIS OTHER QUERY THAT IS SARCHING A WORD IN OTHER TABLE

```
SELECT * FROM videos
                   INNER JOIN contenidos1 ON videos.metadata = contenidos1.id_metadata 
                   WHERE contenidos1.Title LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%"
                   OR contenidos1.Summary_Short LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%"
                   OR contenidos1.Summary_Long LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%"
                   OR contenidos1.Genre LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" LIMIT 10
```

3) AND THIS QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM tableOfContents 
         WHERE tableOfContents .titulo LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
         OR tableOfContents.descripcion LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
         OR tableOfContents.categoria LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
         GROUP BY tableOfContents.titulo  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Can you please tell the number of columns?  
Does these 3 queries return equal number of columns with equal data types?

Comment: Yes, but with different names, for example in table 1 you have NAME, TITLE, and IMAGE. in table 2 NAME, TITLESSS, AND IMAGESSSS... the same but just with different names.

Comment: ok, in this case I think you can use `union` and then give the columns equal names in the query. I'll post an answer for it right now.

Comment: Thank you EhsanT, you are the boss!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

First you have to give the equal names for your columns like this:

instead of using:

```
SELECT * FROM videos  
SELECT * FROM tableOfContents
```

use something like this:

```
SELECT name as col_name, title as col_title, image as col_image FROM videos
SELECT name as col_name, titlesss as col_title, imagesss as col_image FROM tableOfContents
```

you can use any given name for the new column names.
by this, you have equal column names, and then you can use union like this:

```
SELECT name as col_name, title as col_title, image as col_image, 'First_Table' as table_name FROM videos
INNER JOIN programas_videos ON videos.id_video = programas_videos.id_video 
INNER JOIN programas ON programas_videos.id_prog = programas.id_prog 
WHERE programas.nombre_prog LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
OR programas.descrip_larga LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
OR videos.descrip_larga LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
GROUP BY videos.id_video DESC LIMIT 10
union
SELECT name as col_name, titlesss as col_title, imagesss as col_image, 'Second_Table' as table_name  FROM tableOfContents
WHERE tableOfContents .titulo LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
OR tableOfContents.descripcion LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
OR tableOfContents.categoria LIKE "%'.$palabra_buscar.'%" 
GROUP BY tableOfContents.titulo  LIMIT 10
```

I have added `table_name` field so you can distinguish between the rows that are from different tables.

you can use ans many `union`s as you want.
[here you can find the complete union syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Answer (score 0):

After a short google search you could have found this [article](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm), about Sub Queries, or this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) about UNION.

In my opinion you should go with Union, but you need to make sure you select the same COLUMNS in the same order from all the tables. You should resort on subqueries as a last alternative.

Btw. You should bookmark http://www.w3schools.com for future reference in basic Web Developing issues.

Comment: Yes, I made a short search too and i founded the same, but is not so easy as that article.

Comment: Are NOT in the same order and are not the same names.

Comment: So then, assuming you have access to the database, you should just change the columns to be the same for all the tables.

Comment: Moreover, you shouldn't differentiate the columns by adding more 'ss' at the end (i.e. images and imagesss). If there REALLY needs to be a difference make it more obvious and self explanatory (e.g. **images-content** and **images-video**), if NOT then leave it the same for each table.

Comment: And you can also alias your columns using the **AS** operator like - SELECT imagessss as images, videosss as videos FROM...
Same goes for the ordering, you could easily interchange the order of the columns in the SELECT Statement.